# Time taken in creating RDD Vs. Dataframe from HDFS File

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a file on HDFS with below block size configurations.

```
Status: HEALTHY  Total size:    1172387607850 B  Total dirs:    0  Total files:   1  Total symlinks:                0  Total blocks (validated):      8735 (avg. block size 134217241 B)  Minimally replicated blocks:   8735 (100.0 %)  Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)  Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)  Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)  Default replication factor:    3  Average block replication:     3.0  Corrupt blocks:                0  Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)  Number of data-nodes:          16  Number of racks:               1 FSCK ended at Tue Oct 30 02:30:04 EDT 2018 in 75 milliseconds
```

I tried creating RDD using given file with simple command

```
rdd1 = sqlContext.textFile("File HDFS path")  
rdd1.take(50)
```

This command ran in milliseconds

Then I tried to create Dataframe using the same file.It took lot of time as number of tasks created are 8735(No of blocks in file).

```
data_df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
  .option("header", "false") \
  .option("inferschema", "true") \
  .option("delimiter", "|").load(HDFS_FILE_PATH)
```

Number of partitions in dataframe and RDD are same (8735).
What would be the reason for time consumption while creating the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You compare  RDD code

- which does no schema inference,
- no parsing beyond locating new lines,
- and reads only first 50 lines (likely one partition at most).

and `Dataset` code

- which has to parse all records (read all lines of the file)
- and infer the schema.

It is unrealistic to expect that both will take the same amount of time.